# Symfony 6.2 does not reach token handler on token authentication

Tags: symfony, http-token-authentication, symfony-flex

Symfony 6.2 does not reach custom token handler while executing a request if `token_extractors` equals to `header` in the `security.yml`.

Here is the security.yml

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        access_token_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\AccessToken
                property: secret
    firewalls:
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: access_token_provider
            stateless: true
            pattern: ^/
            access_token:
                token_extractors: header
                token_handler: App\Security\AccessTokenHandler
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Here is the custom token handler, as you can see it shoud dump the token and die, and id does that if the token provided in query string.

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\Repository\AccessTokenRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException;
use SensitiveParameter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessToken\AccessTokenHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;

readonly class AccessTokenHandler implements AccessTokenHandlerInterface
{
    public function __construct(private AccessTokenRepository $accessTokenRepository)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @throws NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function getUserBadgeFrom(#[SensitiveParameter] string $accessToken): UserBadge
    {
        var_dump($accessToken);
        die;
        $accessToken = $this->accessTokenRepository->getOneByToken($accessToken);

        if (!$accessToken || !$accessToken->isValid()) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid credentials.');
        }

        return new UserBadge($accessToken->getId());
    }
}
```

Authorization header generated by API client looks like this:
`Authorization: Bearer 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

What's wrong in my implementation?

I tried to change `token_extractors` to `query_string` and provide token in GET parameters, and it does reach.

Query string looks like this:
`localhost:8001/users?access_token=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by Apache misconfiguration.
Apache didn't pass Authorization token to PHP due to default configuration and security reasons.
Adding `CGIPassAuth On` to a directory context solved this.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        CGIPassAuth On
</Directory>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#cgipassauth

Answer (score 0):

Base on `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessToken\HeaderAccessTokenExtractor`  Authorization token have to match this regex `/^%s([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\+~\/\.]+)$/`.
For my case I use `@` character and itwas not working with `header`.